# Why isn't my SESSION data being updated after POSTing to the same page?

Tags: php, session, post, redirect, header

I'm trying to figure out why this is happening. I'll have the user be @ login.php and enter their login credentials as seen in panel (1) below.

Then after successfully matching their credentials to the ones stored in the database, I'll assign a $_SESSION['username'] variable and the page is POSTed to itself (action=""), and I'll alert the user that the session variable has been set.

Ideally, I'd like to not have to alert the user the session variable has been set, and just automatically start using that $_SESSION['username'] variable immediately after they click login (and are verified successfully).

How can I achieve this? I've tried to mess around with headers by putting something like

```
<? if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
?>
```

But I keep getting a headers already sent error because some of the output (like my CSS, JS files) precede the form validation logic on the login.php page.

[image: problem]

Comment: Why not just move your `header()` to the top of the page before all the other things output?

Comment: @Kyle, Possibly, I am. Never thought of it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of operations.

Place your session creation and test-for-validity check at the very top of the page so the rest of the page can make judgment calls off the existence of `$_SESSION['username']`

*(Chances are you're trying to validate them inside the content area so your "yay" or "ney" message appears in the desired section of the document. Pretty, yes, but the whole top-half of the page can't see that it's [potentially] a valid session.)*

Comment: Awesome! That did it. Thanks! I guess it is more efficient, but does appear a little messier.

Comment: @bob_cobb: You can always store the display text in a variable, then output it where you'd like to see it. ;-)