# PHP- Fix problem where sessions only take effect after refreshing

Tags: php, forms, session, post, header

Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228795/why-isnt-my-session-data-being-updated-after-posting-to-the-same-page) Stackoverflow post.

I have the same PHP problem as bob_cobb. Here's Brad Chrisite's answer:

> Order of operations.
>
> Place your session creation and
>   test-for-validity check at the very 
>   top of the page so the rest of the
>   page can make judgment calls off the 
>   existence of $_SESSION['username']
>
> (Chances are you're trying to validate
>   them inside the content area so  your
>   "yay" or "ney" message appears in the
>   desired section of the document. 
>   Pretty, yes, but the whole top-half of
>   the page can't see that it's 
>   [potentially] a valid session.)

He is basically saying that session_start() and the conditionals that check for session variables should be at the top, so that the rest of the page could act based upon that.

However, my session-check ***is*** at the top of the page.

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username']) 
//User is already logged in, echo the log out button.
...    

else 
//User is not logged in, echo the log in form & button.
...    

//Login form validation if user is not logged in and submitted form.
//At the end, create session variable ($_SESSION['username'])

//Destroy session if user pressed log out button.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Everything works fine, but, as with the poster of the other question, I have to refresh my page, to get the ***top*** script executed (the script that checks for $_SESSION['username']).

Why is that?

Comment: @user805556, what exactly is the problem?  We need much more information to help you.  Start by explaining what is in `$_SESSION` and where it gets set.

Comment: I thought I made the problem pretty clear. Just like the other guy, my scripts that are supposed to read for session variables only get executed after a refresh. $_SESSION accesses the document's session, and gets set when the user logs in. I'll add that.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I didn't know that people actually take the points so seriously...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not echo anything before your entire control flow is finished. What I mean by this is that you should work to separate logic from display (even better: use a pattern like [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). In your case, maybe you can do something like this:

```
<?php
/* Place all your control logic at the beginning.
   Do not echo anything in this block. */

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username']) {
  $loggedin = true;
} else {
  $loggedin = false;
  ...    

  //Login form validation if user is not logged in and submitted form.
  //If login succeeded, set $loggedin to true.
  //At the end, create session variable.
}

//Destroy session if user pressed log out button.
  session_destroy();

/* Only display logic below, we do not change any state here */

if($loggedin) {
  echo logout button
} else {
  echo login form
}
?>
```

Comment: It works, I just forgot to set $loggedin to true before. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. You need not unset the session after making the user registration.
Try this

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['username']) 
//User is already logged in, echo the log out button.
...    

else 
//User is not logged in, echo the log in form & button.
...    

//Login form validation if user is not logged in and submitted form.
//At the end, create session variable.

//Destroy session if user pressed log out button.
//session_destroy();
--- do a redirect or a refresh here .... 
?>
```

Comment: How do I do a redirect or refresh? I thought that that's only possible in the header. Do you mean via Javascript? That doesn't work, I tried it.

Comment: Where he does redirect, you use PHP's header()

Comment: Yes, but then I can't put that at the bottom of the page. I thought headers have to go on the top.